# Automatic binning of histogram using raw gnuplot in pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pgfplots, gnuplot

I have a problem in plotting a histogram using the raw gnuplot in pgfplot. A minimal example is below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{external/force remake}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{filecontents*}{datafile}
-0.000632
0.004692
0.001407
0.005768
0.003117
0.001605
0.001742
-0.000874
-0.000973
-0.000436
-0.001578
-0.001953
-0.004275
-0.001585
-0.000957
-0.000819
-0.000924
-0.003559
0.001949
-0.000300
-0.003085
-0.002050
-0.000493
-0.001378
-0.000970
0.000912
0.001667
-0.000974
-0.000592
-0.000865
-0.000933
0.000435
-0.001278
0.001508
-0.000566
-0.003608
0.002768
0.005676
0.000331
-0.000527
-0.000589
-0.000751
-0.000503
-0.000718
-0.000950
-0.005616
-0.004347
-0.001818
-0.000503
0.001063
0.002109
-0.004156
-0.002612
-0.000773
-0.000635
-0.000218
-0.001041
-0.001247
-0.000283
-0.004434
-0.000370
0.002669
0.001302
0.001351
0.001618
0.002028
0.001291
0.004341
0.001141
0.001058
-0.004537
-0.000123
-0.000052
0.000010
-0.000643
0.001403
-0.000751
-0.000201
-0.001639
-0.000316
-0.000757
-0.000872
0.000530
-0.000969
-0.000826
-0.001076
-0.000808
0.001687
0.001356
0.001870
0.001016
0.002165
0.005372
0.001128
0.002269
0.001878
0.000839
-0.000798
-0.000846
0.000146
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{histogram.tikz}
\tikzsetnextfilename{Fig-Histogram}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmode=linear,
        ymode=linear,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line*=left,
        tick label style={font=\small},
        grid=both,
        tick align=outside, 
        tickpos=left,
        xlabel=Bins,
        ylabel=Count,
        width=0.45\textwidth,
        height=0.4\textwidth,
    ]
    \addplot+[raw gnuplot, color=red] gnuplot {
        binwidth=0.001;
        bin(x,bw)=bw*floor(x/bw);
        plot "datafile" using (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq with boxes;
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{figure}[bth]
    \begin{tabular}{p{3in}}
        \includegraphics[]{histogram}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{\small{Histogram.}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Compile with

```
pdflatex -shell-escape main.tex
```

No correct histogram is resulted. The generated plot is [image]

I have verified the correctness of the body of the raw plot using a try.plot as below.

```
set terminal postscript enhanced color "Times-Roman" 20

set xlabel "bins"
set ylabel "count"
set yrange [0:]

binwidth=0.0005
bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)

set output "./try.eps"

plot "datafile.tex" using (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq with boxes
```

The resulted plot is
[image]

How can I do the following three things?

1. How to make the binning to be the same as it is in gnu plot?
2. How to make the automatic binned data to be sorted?
3. How to specify plotting in boxes in raw gnuplot?

Comment: For third Q: `[raw gnuplot,color=red,hist={data=x}]` would give histogram. Using gnuplot only benefits for writing larger data into a `.table` (read by pgfplots) and when high precision is required. `pgfplots` can also plot histogram using `datafile.dat` something like `\addplot+[hist={bins=22}] file {datafile.dat}`, although no in depth idea of changing the bin size and normalisation etc.. Look into [5.9.2,page 383, pgfplots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf)

Comment: [raw gnuplot,color=red,hist={data=x}] does not work for me. No bins are plotted using this option.

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell PGFPlots that you want the data to be plotted as a column diagram by using the option `ybar`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}


\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{external/force remake}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{datafile.dat}
-0.000632
0.004692
0.001407
0.005768
0.003117
0.001605
0.001742
-0.000874
-0.000973
-0.000436
-0.001578
-0.001953
-0.004275
-0.001585
-0.000957
-0.000819
-0.000924
-0.003559
0.001949
-0.000300
-0.003085
-0.002050
-0.000493
-0.001378
-0.000970
0.000912
0.001667
-0.000974
-0.000592
-0.000865
-0.000933
0.000435
-0.001278
0.001508
-0.000566
-0.003608
0.002768
0.005676
0.000331
-0.000527
-0.000589
-0.000751
-0.000503
-0.000718
-0.000950
-0.005616
-0.004347
-0.001818
-0.000503
0.001063
0.002109
-0.004156
-0.002612
-0.000773
-0.000635
-0.000218
-0.001041
-0.001247
-0.000283
-0.004434
-0.000370
0.002669
0.001302
0.001351
0.001618
0.002028
0.001291
0.004341
0.001141
0.001058
-0.004537
-0.000123
-0.000052
0.000010
-0.000643
0.001403
-0.000751
-0.000201
-0.001639
-0.000316
-0.000757
-0.000872
0.000530
-0.000969
-0.000826
-0.001076
-0.000808
0.001687
0.001356
0.001870
0.001016
0.002165
0.005372
0.001128
0.002269
0.001878
0.000839
-0.000798
-0.000846
0.000146
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmode=linear,
        ymode=linear,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line*=left,
        tick label style={font=\small},
        grid=both,
        tick align=outside, 
        tickpos=left,
        xlabel=Bins,
        ylabel=Count,
        width=0.45\textwidth,
        height=0.4\textwidth,
        ybar, bar width=0.001,
        ymin=0
    ]
    \addplot+[raw gnuplot, color=red] gnuplot {
        binwidth=0.001;
        bin(x,bw)=bw*floor(x/bw);
        plot "datafile.dat" using (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq with boxes;
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked for me. But, I have further questions. The ybar option in the axis section is global to the whole figure. If I plot another curve in the same plot as the histogram, then the new curve is also plotted as ybar. How to turn off the ybar option in the options of a \addplot? I have tried this \addplot+[ybar=false] and failed.

Comment: I moved the ybar option to the options of \addplot as in \addplot+[only marks,ybar,bar width=2.0,raw gnuplot,color=red]. It worked. Thanks.